# <c:param> value attribute not working properly

Tags: jsp, jstl

In my Java spring mvc web app, I want to pass a request parameter in a link. Following is a portion of a .jsp page code `

```
           <c:url var = "updateLink" value="/customer/showFormForUpdate">
           <c:param name="customerId" value="${tempCustomer.id}"></c:param>
           </c:url>

           <c:forEach var="tempCustomer" items="${customers}">

             <tr>
                <td> ${tempCustomer.firstName} </td>
                <td> ${tempCustomer.lastName} </td> 
                <td> ${tempCustomer.email} </td>
                <td> ${tempCustomer.id} </td>



                <td>    <a href="${updateLink}">Update</a> </td>
```

The portion of code below works perfectly fine..It displays the Customer ID for the 'tempCustomer'.

```
<td> ${tempCustomer.id} </td>
```

However,

```
<c:url var = "updateLink" value="/customer/showFormForUpdate">
       <c:param name="customerId" value="${tempCustomer.id}"></c:param>
```

this portion of the code doesnt work fine. The value="${tempCustomer.id}" simply doesn't pass the value of tempCustomer.id. When I click, the update link

```
   <td>    <a href="${updateLink}">Update</a> </td>
```

the url looks like this

> http://localhost:8080/web-customer-tracker/customer/showFormForUpdate?customerId=

The parameter value is absent. The url is supposed to contain the customerId parameter's value.

For complete reference, here is the full .jsp page code

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>List Customers</title>




<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
 href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css"/>


</head>
<body>

        <div id ="wrapper">
            <div id ="header">
                <h2>CRM - Customer Relationship Manager</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id ="container">

            <div id = "content">

            <input type="button" value="Add Customer"
            onclick="window.location.href='showFormForAdd';return false;"
            class="add-button"          />


            <table>
               <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
              </tr>

               <!-- ${tempCustomer.id}
                -->
               <c:url var = "updateLink" value="/customer/showFormForUpdate">
               <c:param name="customerId" value="${tempCustomer.id}"></c:param>
               </c:url>

               <c:forEach var="tempCustomer" items="${customers}">

                 <tr>
                    <td> ${tempCustomer.firstName} </td>
                    <td> ${tempCustomer.lastName} </td> 
                    <td> ${tempCustomer.email} </td>
                    <td> ${tempCustomer.id} </td>



                    <td>    <a href="${updateLink}">Update</a> </td>


               </c:forEach>

            </table>


            </div>

        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       <c:url var = "updateLink" value="/customer/showFormForUpdate">
           <c:param name="customerId" value="${tempCustomer.id}"></c:param>
       </c:url>

       <c:forEach var="tempCustomer" items="${customers}">

         <tr>
            <td> ${tempCustomer.firstName} </td>
            <td> ${tempCustomer.lastName} </td> 
            <td> ${tempCustomer.email} </td>
            <td> ${tempCustomer.id} </td>
```

You defined the **tempCustomer** variable in your **c:forEach**. It only exists in the scope of the c:forEach. Move your **c:url** block under the **c:forEach.**

Comment: Happens to the best of us ;-)